# "Expression you entered requires the control to be in the active window" error - can't find where it's coming from

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to create a control that moves from one form to another and goes to a specific record on the new form.  However I'm getting some odd errors that just don't make much sense to me (code wise).  Additionally, even if I open the form `frmService` from the object explorer window, I don't get the error but the form opens completely blank.

[image: Image of the error and blank screen]
[image: Image of the form and control being used to open frmService]

Originally the first form (`frmWorkOrders`) was part of another form via a subform.  But I had some unfixable bugs that forced me to create an entirely new form and I moved all the fields and data over.  It works perfectly on it's own.  However, when I attempt to open `frmService` using a control on `frmWorkOrders` I get an error upon opening `frmService` stating:

> The expression you entered requires the control to be in the active
>   window.

The code to open and close the forms is pretty darn simple, so I'm not sure why it's having errors.

This is ALL the code on `frmService` which is where the error is occurring.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmService"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmWorkOrders", acNormal
End Sub

Private Sub cmdComputer_Click()
 Me.Computer.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdFirst_Click()
 Me.FirstStage.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdHPSPG_Click()
 Me.HPSPG.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdInflator_Click()
 Me.Inflator.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOcto_Click()
 Me.Octo.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSecond_Click()
 Me.SecondStage.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command86_Click()
 Me.Computer.SetFocus
End Sub
```

And here's the code to open `frmService` and close `frmWorkOrders`.

```
Private Sub cmdService_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdService_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmService", , , "tblRegSR.[ID] = " & Me!txtID
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "frmService", acFirst, "[WorkOrderID] = " & Me.txtID
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmWorkOrders"

cmdService_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdService_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
   Resume cmdService_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

And just in case it's an SQL issue, here's the SQL statement for `frmService`.

```
SELECT tblRegSR.*, [tblCustomers].[FName] & " " & [LName] AS FullName, tblWorkOrder.Task, "WD0" & [tblWorkOrder]![ID] AS WONumber, tblFirstSR.*, tblHPSPGSR.*, tblInflatorSR.*, tblOctoSR.*, tblSecondSR.*, tblComputerSR.*
FROM ((((((tblCustomers RIGHT JOIN (tblWorkOrder INNER JOIN tblRegSR ON tblWorkOrder.ID = tblRegSR.ID) ON tblCustomers.ID = tblWorkOrder.CustomerID) 
INNER JOIN tblComputerSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblComputerSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblFirstSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblFirstSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblHPSPGSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblHPSPGSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblInflatorSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblInflatorSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblOctoSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblOctoSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblSecondSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblSecondSR.ServiceRecordID;
```

Comment: Don't use `Screen.ActiveControl`, explicitly reference control you want value of.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - but why on earth did the Macro builder put that in there then?  Also, thanks a ton for the edit.

Comment: Why I don't use most of the wizards - they do things I don't like.

Comment: Ok - I FINALLY got back to this (was off for the weekend) and changed `Screen.ActiveControl` to `Me.txtID` and I'm getting a different error with the same end result (`frmService` opens with the error and is completely blank).  Updating the original posting to show the updates I made to the code.

Comment: I'm an idiot - I forgot to put in the new error.  I'm getting the `The Object Type argument for the action or method is blank or invalid` error and still stuck with the blank screen.  One other thing I noticed is it's not getting to the point where it closes `frmWorkOrders`.

Comment: I created a new post because the new problem is effectively a new problem.  Thanks for the advice @June7.

Comment: Not seeing field WorkOrderID in that query. There is WONumber. Could open form filtered to the one record instead of all records.